# Phase diagram of ${\rm O}(3)$ lattice model and mean field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, phase-transition, lattice-model

In [David Tong: Lectures on Statistical Field Theory](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/sft.html) Problem Sheet 1 exist task:

[image]

I fully understand this problem and I know solution: [section 17.2](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/rrh/notes/qstat.pdf).

I am interested in application of mean field theory to this problem. Essence of problem in founding number of configurations $\Omega(\vec{m})$ with fixed average spin $\vec{m}$:

$$
\vec{m} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_i \vec{s}_i
$$
And if one know this, one can easily obtain effective free energy $f(\vec{m})$:
$$
e^{-\beta N f(\vec{m})} = \Omega(\vec{m}) e^{-\beta E(\vec{m})}
$$

From here I can easily study properties of effective free energy and understand qualitative this phase diagram.

Could somebody explain me how to calculate $\Omega(\vec{m})$?